# Using forever.js with Python

Tags: python, forever

Two questions:

- Is there a Python equivalent to forever.js to run a Python process in the background without requiring sudo?
- Is it possible to use forever.js with Python? How about with a virtualenv?

Comment: `forever start -c python server.py`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is easy to use Python with forever.js:

```
forever start -c python python_script.py
```

To use it with virtualenv is a little bit more complicated, I did it using a bash script (call it `python_virtualenv`):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to run a Python file using the local virtualenv
source bin/activate
bin/python $@
```

Now use that script with forever:

```
forever start -c ./python_virtualenv python_script.py
```

Comment: I'd use the correct path to the virtualenv Python script instead: `forever start -c bin/python python_script.py`.

Comment: How to make a json file for this?

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems executing a python script with custom logging paths, after trying I got to work with the next command:

```
 forever start -c python -l /tmp/forever.log -o /tmp/out.log -e /tmp/error.log python_script.py
```

Tell me if it worked for you

Comment: Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Answer (score 0):

Using python 3 with Flask to run with forever.js, here is my build process

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
sudo -H pip3 install -r requirements.txt
FLASK_APP=app.py forever start -c python3 app.py --port=5001
```