# Restart python script

Tags: python

I have a script that collects data from the streaming API. I'm getting an error at random that I believe it's coming from twitter's end for whatever reason. It doesn't happen at specific time, I've been seen it as early as 10 minutes after running my script, and other times after 2 hours.

My question is how do I create another script (outside the running one) that can catch if it terminated with an error, then restart after a delay.

I did some searching and most were related to using bash on linux, I'm on windows. Other suggestions were to use Windows Task Scheduler but that can only be set for a known time.

I came across the following code:

```
import os, sys, time

def main():  
    print "AutoRes is starting"
    executable = sys.executable
    args = sys.argv[:]
    args.insert(0, sys.executable)

    time.sleep(1)
    print "Respawning"
    os.execvp(executable, args)

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    main()
```

If I'm not mistaken that runs inside the code correct? Issue with that is my script is currently collecting data and I can't terminate to edit.

Comment: Can you _detect_ when your script goes wrong? At that point you can throw an exception.

Comment: ... and use forever ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571282/using-forever-js-with-python

Comment: I do have an exception but it doesn't capture that error, it captures errors once I receive data from the API and works for that. That's why I believe it might be a connection problem between me and twitter.

Comment: @Leb but in general, can you tell when you script goes wrong? At that point, call `sys.exit(1)`

Comment: @JuanPablo I need a delay, otherwise twitter won't appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
from os import system
from time import sleep

while True: #manually terminate when you want to stop streaming
    system('python streamer.py')
    sleep(300) #sleep for 5 minutes
```

In the meanwhile, when something goes wrong in `streamer.py` , end it from there by invoking `sys.exit(1)`

Make sure this and `streamer.py` are in the same directory.

Comment: @Leb this is a separate “controller” script.

Comment: Depending on what exactly `streamer.py` does, you could end up with multiple streamer.py instances. Also, you might have to wait 5 minutes before you deal with the errornous `streamer.py`

Comment: @moose how is that possible?

Comment: @moose just asking, I’m not an expert.

Comment: @moose isn’t a call to `system` blocking?

Comment: @RishavKundu True, I forgot about this. (I guess there are ways where you can still get multiple instances, e.g. when you fork the process, but that's probably not the case). Still, you will execute the script every 5 minutes and have to wait 5 minutes before you deal with the error case.

Comment: @moose I just tested. calls to `system` are indeed blocking. Another instance will be not be launched till the previous terminates...

Comment: @moose OP wants to have a timeout before relaunching his streamer. And `you will execute the script every 5 minutes`, how?

Comment: @RishavKundu I did a dummy run on another script and it worked. I can't use it on my main one because it'll create another connection. Once the current one terminate I'll run it and update.

Comment: @Leb if you want, you can add a `print “Relaunching”` on the last line of the while loop, if you want to know how many time your script crashed.

Comment: @Leb thats nice. By the way, what’s streaming in the context of twitter?